# Html page in windows phone8.1

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-8.1

How to call Html page in windows phone8.1 using webview 
my xaml code is:

```
<StackPanel>
    <WebView x:Name="myWebView"
             Height="550"
             VerticalAlignment="Top"
             Source="ms-appx:///html/Home.html" />
    <TextBox Margin="10,95,124,0"
             VerticalAlignment="Top"
             Text="ms-appx:///html/Home.html" />
</StackPanel>
```

I created file name Home.html inside I used .js and .css styles and .cs code:

```
var html = await Windows.Storage.PathIO.ReadTextAsync("ms-appx:///html/Home.html");
this.myWebView.NavigateToString(html);
```

But its not working? If someone have idea of this help me.

Comment: What exactly is not working? Does your page get displayed? Do your JS/Css get loaded?

Comment: JS and CSS content not loading and i used ms-appx-web:// i got error like this " An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code"

Comment: thanks its working - Kai Brummund

Answer (score 1):

To access resources from within WebView, you have to use the ms-appx-web:// protocol.

(Only for your .css etc. Files. Not for the direct loading you do before using NavigateToString.)